# How to fix category url 404's after category permalink change

Tags: htaccess, seo

I am working on SEO for a website.
So, I wanted to append "-coupon-codes" to all category URLs.

My Category Base Slug is : stores

Example what I wanted to achieve redirection :

```
/stores/walmart to /stores/walmart-coupon-codes
```

as stores/walmart is indexed in google, I want to 301 redirect to new url

I tried this htaccess :

```
RewriteRule ^stores/(.*)/$ /stores/$1-coupon-codes [R=301,NC,L]
```

This was redirecting all store links to /stores-coupon-code
but its 404 as original category URL doesn't contain -coupon-codes,

and if I change any permalink to include -coupon-codes,
Then, the original store URL becomes 404, and redirection isn't working.

Comment: "This was redirecting all store links to /stores-coupon-code" - presumably you mean `/stores/<storename>-coupon-codes`?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^stores/(.*)/$ /stores/$1-coupon-codes [R=301,NC,L]
> ```

You can perhaps use a *negative lookahead assertion* to exclude URLs that already contain `-coupon-codes` from being redirected *again*, thus preventing a redirect-loop (which I assume is what's happening here).

For example:

```
RewriteRule ^stores/(?!.*-coupon-codes)(.+)/$ /stores/$1-coupon-codes [R=301,NC,L]
```

The negative lookahead `(?!`...`)` causes the pattern match to fail when the URL already contains `-coupon-codes`.

You'll need to clear your browser cache and I'd recommend testing first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

However, there are some inconsistencies here... you gave the example `/stores/walmart` (no trailing slash). But the rule you stated (which you say *does* redirect) would only redirect a URL that includes a trailing slash. If the original URL included a trailing slash then there would be no redirect loop here (since the URL you are redirecting to does not include a trailing slash), unless... *something else* is appending a trailing slash?

> **UPDATE:** Its working only for URL with slash at the end . Is there any fix for that ? Like appending slash to all URLs of the site if they doesn't have it already .

Yes, you can make the trailing slash *optional* in the above regex. However, you also need to make the preceding capturing group (ie. `(.+)`) non-greedy, ie. `(.+?)` so that it doesn't consume the *optional* trailing slash. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^stores/(?!.*-coupon-codes)(.+?)/?$ /stores/$1-coupon-codes [R=301,NC,L]
```

I wouldn't "append a slash" to all URLs *before* this redirect, since that would incur another redirect. You could naturally append a slash to the resulting *substitution* string if that is what you want. ie. `/stores/$1-coupon-codes/`.

> One more issue I figured out while pagination, the URLs are broken : `stores/walmart/page/2-coupon-codes`, as its appending it like this

You could add a *condition* to exclude URLs that end with a number in the last path segment. eg. `/stores/walmart/page/2` or `/<anything>/<number>`. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/\d+$
RewriteRule ^stores/(?!.*-coupon-codes)(.+?)/?$ /stores/$1-coupon-codes [R=301,NC,L]
```

The `!` prefix on the *CondPattern* (2nd argument to the `RewriteCond` directive) negates the comparison, so it is successful when the regex does not match. In this case, it is successful when the URL-path does not end with a path segment consisting only of digits.

> but couldn't add a valid regex for negative look ahead.

You don't *need* to use a negative lookahead, you could use an additional *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) instead. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/\d+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-coupon-codes/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^stores/(.+?)/?$ /stores/$1-coupon-codes [R=301,NC,L]
```

I didn't just mention this above, as you seem to already be putting the directives in the correct place, but these directives need to go near the top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the WordPress front-controller.

Comment: Perfect, this is what I tried to do it, but couldn't add a valid regex for negative look ahead. Its working only for URL with slash at the end . Is there any fix for that ? Like appending slash to all URLs of the site if they doesn't have it already .

Comment: One more issue I figured out while pagination, the URLs are broken : stores/walmart/page/2-coupon-codes , as its appending it like this

Comment: I've updated my answer addressing these issues.

Comment: Ah, just thought... I've added an exception for paginated URLs above (so these are not redirected). Or should this be redirected to a URL of the form `/stores/walmart-coupon-codes/page/2` instead? ie. URLs that end in `/page/<number>`?

Answer (score 0):

Put Below Code On .htaccess File ,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^stores/(.*)/$ /stores/$1-coupon-codes [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Redirection is happening to url with -coupon-codes, but when i change the category url to store-coupon-codes, then this redirect is adding one more -coupon-codes to the url, making it 404

Answer (score 0):

You should flush the rewrite rules from the `function.php file`.

```
<?php
/**
* flush_rewrite_rules
* Remove rewrite rules and then recreate rewrite rules.
* @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/
*
* flush_rewrite_rules(); Need to be removed before pushing to live.
* Can be replaced before pushing to live by add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'flush_rewrite_rules' );
*/
flush_rewrite_rules(); ?>
```

Now to update a default category slug, which would then affect the permalink, you should be able to do that from the admin console, on the category management page.